# Diablo 3 open followers window

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2 you could view your follower's stats by pressing "o". Is there a similar shortcut in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the default key for that is <kbd>F</kbd>. You can rebind it from the options screen, where it's called "Toggle Follower Menu":

[image: options menu screenshot]

Comment: Great, thanks! Did it need to change? Wasn't O doing a good job? I thought it was...

Comment: It's also shown when hovering your mouse over follower icon in top left corner

Comment: "O" is now used for the social menu